# Can I be sure that i receive correct item if I defined item in one msbuild target and get it in other one?

Tags: msbuild

I have two different targets which are invoked with one collection of properties via msbuild task. In one target I define ItemGroup and in other one I recieve it. I invoke targets in the next way:

```
<MsBuild Projects="deploypkg.project" Properties="CurrentSite=%(SitesName.Identity)" Targets="TargetA"/>

<MsBuild Projects="deploypkg.project" Properties="CurrentSite=%(SitesName.Identity)" Targets="TargetB"/>
```

When in TargetB I refer defined in TargetA ItemGroup i get items defined only for current site(input property). It's exactly what i need but I'm not sure I can rely on it, because I found nothing about this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sure, you can create test.project to test it. Something like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
    <Target Name="TargetA">
        <Message Text="TargetA: CurrentSite = $(CurrentSite)"/>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="TargetB">
        <Message Text="TargetB: CurrentSite = $(CurrentSite)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Use test.project in your script:

```
<MsBuild Projects="test.project" Properties="CurrentSite=%(SitesName.Identity)" Targets="TargetA"/>
<MsBuild Projects="test.project" Properties="CurrentSite=%(SitesName.Identity)" Targets="TargetB"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it works great but I can't understand why. In the MsBuid task reference I found next: When you pass properties to the project through the Properties parameter, MSBuild creates a new instance of the project even if the project file has already been loaded. When a new instance of the project has been created, MSBuild treats it as a different project that has different global properties and that can be built in parallel with other instances of the project.